# Qt/C++ project VS2010 svn-commit&update .sln

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, svn, solution

Using Tortoise-svn with C++ VS2010 project. I would like to know in which cases you are to commit .sln file.

Some reasons I see for commiting .sln file:

- some projects were added to solution
- dependencies were modified

What other reasons for commiting .sln ? How would .sln be merged ?

Also, who is generating .sln file ? Is it generated at each qmake_all (or make_all) ?

***EDIT***

I am using Tortoise SVN GUI. It should tell me when .sln has been changed by me.

Now, under which circomstances is .sln changed ?

And also: how are .sln merged ?

More pragmatically, in which case should I do accept mine or accept theirs for .sln when I just updated ?

***EDIT***

When/How is .sln produced from .pro file ?

***EDIT***

To make part of my question clearer:

***after an update with tortoise svn, if .sln is conflicted, should i***

- **accept mine** (since anyway .sln will be regenerated from .pro file when i qmakeall) or
- **accept theirs** (since my .sln is no more up to date)
- or is it **not important** ?

thanks!

Comment: It seems that your question is related with the Qt and *.sln-generation using qmake, you might want to indicate that.

Comment: too much questions for a single question, you need to split these into separate questions and ask a question that can be answered, not discussed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for me you do not have needs to store sln file, because sln file is derivative from your pro file (in other words sln is generated from pro file), so consider to storage only primary project definition file (this is a pro file) and omit generated artifacts. The primary reason is when you decide to change developer environment (for example it can be mingw) you can do it in the moment with pro file, and spend a lot of time for converting sln file.

Comment: thanks! when is sln generated from .pro file? on make all ? does it mean that i should always choose `accept mine` in svn for .sln when i update? In the past, i had struggle with compilation (execution?) when using my .sln (svn: accept mine).

Comment: consider to use out source build, for example, src is under SVN control, and vs2010 is local directory contains vs solution and project file. to make out source solution you should enter into vs2010 and run qmake -tp vc ..\src\myproject.pro In that case you should not solve any svn specific task, because the generated solution will be out of svn scope.

Comment: i did not fully understand your answer. maybe i was not clear enough: after an update with tortoise svn, if .sln is conflicted, should i accept mine (since anyway .sln will be regenerated from .pro file when i qmakeall) or accept theirs (since my .sln is no more up to date) - or is it not important ? thanks!

Comment: my answer was "you have not put sln under svn control" and I described how it can be reached.

Comment: I guess if I don't manually `add` .sln with tortoise svn, then it would not be added to svn repository... isn't it that simple ?

Comment: if you find it comfortable to have source and build artifacts in one directory, certainly you can continue to use your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Usually any svn GUI like TutoiseSVN will detect any changes in the solution file and will warn you to commit .sln file as well but if you are not using such a GUI, then you can find related solution parameters by opening .sln file with a text editor like Notepad++ and you can see all the variables about your project